# Particle moving in Morse potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, potential, hamiltonian

I'm solving for a particle moving in the Morse's potential

$$
H=\frac{p^2}{2m}+A\left( e^{-2\alpha x}-2e^{-\alpha x}\right)
$$

Now, considering an operator $B=-\partial_x +C e^{-\alpha x}-D$ and its hermitian conjugate $B^{\dagger}$; I have to find the values of $C$ and $D$ which make the Hamiltonian look like

$$ H=B^{\dagger}B+k $$

Here, $k$ is a constant. Assumption made is that all the constants are complex numbers, so that $B\neq B^{\dagger}$. I haven't been able to get anything even close to what I'm looking for. Especially, I doubt that the calculation of $B^{\dagger}B$, where, I get terms like $-\partial_x Ce^{-\alpha x}$ or $\partial_x D$.

Is it alright to have derivative terms, like the above, in here? Or should i just leave it as it is and keep on with those kind of expressions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at B, C and D have to be constants, real or complex. So just do the derivative and compare the two Hamiltonians.

Comment: I tried to do that, but having the derivative there is no good, so instead I used the relation $\hat{p}=-i\hbar \partial_x$ and that kind of worked.

Comment: Since, derivative of a constant is zero, shouldn't it make the terms you mentioned to disappear?

Comment: Well, only for the term $\partial_x  D$, the other one depends on $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a general Schroedinger factorization
$$
B= -\partial_x+ q(x)\\
B^\dagger =\partial_x+q(x).
$$
Expand out  to get
$$
B^\dagger B= (\partial_x+q)(-\partial_x+q) = - \partial^2_x + [q(x)]^2 + q'(x).
$$
You are being asked to find a $q(x)$ so that $q^2+q'$ looks like  $e^{-2x} -2 e^{-x}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mike. Indeed the exercise can be done this way.